# Hypothesis Test Where Test Statistic Equals the Critical Value

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Assume that we are performing a one-sided hypothesis test where $H_{0}:\:\mu=0$
and $H_{1}:\;\mu>0$. A critical value equal to $z$ is calculated,
and the calculated test statistic happens to exactly equal $z$. Is
the null hypothesis rejected?

Comment: What exactly is your model? Is $\mu$ the mean of a normal distribution or something else?

Comment: Note that tehre are many tests, and one cannot rely that notation is unified, so you better explain your notation, also the $z$.

Comment: If you have a specific significance level (say 1%) in mind, then it would be possible (but unlikely) that your test statistic would exactly match your critical value to several decimal places. Then you could say you reject $H_0$ (exactly at the critical 1% value) or you could consider whether it is appropriate to test at some other level (e.g., 5% level or 0.5% level) instead of the 1% level.

Comment: There is no right answer. It comes down to what you mean by "critical value."  If your definition is that the critical value $C$ should result in rejection whenever the statistic equals or exceeds $C,$ for instance, then you get one answer; but if you define $C$ so that rejection occurs only when the test statistic exceeds $C,$ then you get another answer.

Comment: While that's true I'd say that the most common convention has the critical value in the rejection region (e.g. of the tables of discrete critical values I can recall seeing, as far as I remember none of them did otherwise)

Comment: @Glen_b That's not the only convention, though.  For instance, in some regulatory situations where falling within the critical region results in an "enforceable action" and the statistic is, *for practical purposes,* discrete (due to reporting to a finite number of significant figures), government agencies have tended to view values on the boundary as *not* significant. For this reason some agencies have promulgated rules concerning how many significant figures to use for reporting results (!).

Comment: @whuber You hit the nail right on the head! My real question is: Using the critical value as a decision level (DL), is an analytical result (rounded to 1 or 2 significant digits) equal to the DL an indication that the level of analyte in the sample is (or is not) significantly greater than background?

Comment: It depends on the rounding.  The differences are rarely worth fussing over except where you are committed to making a formal decision based on the observational outcome.  By far the best thing to do in those circumstances is to stipulate beforehand (in your permit, memorandum of agreement, or other controlling document) how such situations will be decided.

Comment: @Thomas when you're unavoidably dealing with rounding and want a formal decision rule with exact-or-conservative significance level, it's important to consider exactly what is happening with that rounding. [It may in some situations be worth looking to something like a permutation test perhaps, perhaps even going to exact calculation of the tail in small samples]

Comment: Maybe OT, but since the choice of significance level $\alpha$ is fairly arbitrary, it is hard (at least for me) to see cases where committing to a certain decision should really depend on whether a test statistic is rounded (with the issue being "totally moot" for continuously distributed test statistics) to exactly the c.v. at that $\alpha$ or not, when it is then *not* rounded to another equally defensible c.v. at $\alpha'=\alpha+\epsilon$.